# Drools kie workbench guided decision table

Tags: java, drools, kie

Using drools decision table with spreadsheet I was able to make this:
[decision table with xls file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOr3D.png)
But in workbench I can´t 
[guided decision table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6sGY.png)
The error I was getting is:

```
Unable to Analyse Expression entrega.setSeq1( ""number|"+entrega.getNumeroML|()" );:
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: org.drools.core.spi.KnowledgeHelper.verbalizar()]
[Near : {... rega.setSeq1( ""number|"+entrega.ge ....}] ^ [Line: 5, Column: 0]
```

How to set a fact value in action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:
From:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-usage/ZM76HPQ62cU

Create a "Action BRL Fragment" (you'll need to click the "Include advanced options" on the new column dialog).

With this you can either:-

(1) Add "free form DRL" and enter entrega.setSeq1( "number|"+entrega.getNum() );

(2) Select "modify entrega", select the Seq1 field and use a "formula" for the value entering "number|"+entrega.getNum()